# Closest point out of collision

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, collision-detection

I am tackling IMO very hard problem from geometry "How to find closest point out of collision".

To explain it better I've drawn an image explaining it. Basically: given a point on 2D plane( yellow dot) I want to find closest point( blue one ) on plane not affected by collision( green part ) objects( orange ones ).

[image: collision explaination]

Is there any smart way of finding this point?

Comment: You need to be more precise

Comment: How are the orange shapes defined?  In this case, it looks like you just need to find the intersection of the circle and the rectangle.  Are you trying to have a program find the point for a large collection of problems?

Comment: Orange shapes are either circle or circle part or rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the orange stuff is made out of seimple shapes as here (polygons and circles), there are only a few candidates for the point you are looking for: Either the blue point is an intersection of two boundary lines, or it is a concave vertex of a nonconvex polygon, or it is the orthogonal projection onto a polygon edge, or it is the intersection of a cricle with the line through th eyellow point and the circle  center. You need only test these finitely many points if they are valid (i.e. not covered by another shape) and pick the closest one.

Comment: Could you explain what is concave vertex f a nonconvex polygon? The rest I can understand and thought about it earlier, but wasn't sure it is that simple :) And does having part of circles changes in collision changes something?